# Newly created jobs need to be set for failure notifications automatically

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, jobs

Whenever a new / existing job gets failed on an instance of SQL Server, we should recieve an email about failure notification. Please help on how we can automate it?

Comment: Create an Operator, and configure "Alert System" in SQL Server Agent property and restart it (SQL Server Agent). Simple.

Comment: Have a look at this article: [Configure a SQL Server Agent Operator](https://www.sqlserverscience.com/sql-server-agent/configure-operator/)

Comment: @RajeshRanjan I am not talking about configuring alert for one job. and the setting you are talking about will only configure alerting system in Agent which is not my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest checking out this post from Greg Larsen - [Automating SQL Server Agent Notification](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/automating-sql-server-agent-notification.html).  You could manually create a SQL Agent job that runs periodically and searches for enabled jobs that don't have any notifications defined.

Here's an example of a dynamic SQL query you could put in a SQL Agent job to find SQL agent jobs without notifications and dynamically update them to have notifications.  Make sure you uncomment the `EXEC` when you put it in a SQL Agent job.  You will also have to modify the variable `@Operator` to specify the operator you want notified.

```
USE [msdb]
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @ExecStmt VARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @Operator VARCHAR(50) = 'DBA' -- place your operator name here

SELECT @ExecStmt = STUFF((
            SELECT ';' + 'EXEC sp_update_job @job_name = ''' + j.[name] + ''', @notify_email_operator_name = ''' + @Operator + ''', @notify_level_email = 2' -- 1=On Success, 2=On Faulure,3=always
            FROM dbo.sysjobs j
            WHERE j.enabled = 1
                AND j.notify_level_email <> 1
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
PRINT @ExecStmt
--exec (@ExecStmt) 
GO
```